# tModLoader SDL Error: Wave Bank.xwb can't be found

Tags: technical-issues, terraria, mods

My PC crashed whilst I was playing, and when I tried to reboot, my tModLoader gave me the error shown in the image below.

[image: tModLoader error message]

> Main Engine crash
> SDL Error:
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find asset 'Wave Bank.xwb'.

My platform is GOG on Windows 10.
My mods are Calamity + Calamity Music, Magic storage, OreExcavator, Recipe browser, and a couple of others I can't remember that were popular QoL mods.

Is there any way to fix this without losing my saves?

Comment: Hi LGA, you can post your answer to your own question, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer moved from edit history of question:

---

Nevermind, I solved it, all you have to do is Reinstall Terraria and TML, and then when the red console prompt appears, DO NOT HIT ENTER! instead, try to close the console, some more text in white will appear, and the TML will boot up! All of your World/Characters are stored separately, So no need to worry!